# How to solve Object cannot be converted to List issue?

Tags: android, android-room

```
@Entity(tableName = DBConstants.TABLE_USER_PROFILE, indices = {@Index(value = {DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_USERID}, unique = true)})
public class User extends BaseProfileInfo implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_ROWID)
    private int rowId;

    @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_USERID)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_USERID)
    private int id;

    @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_SNOMED_ALERGIES)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_SNOMED_ALERGIES)
    @Nullable
    public List<SnomedAllergy> snomed_allergies = null;
    
    }
```

> build time spacing following error
> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to List
> _item_1.snomed_allergies = CommonConverter.fromObjectString(_tmp_3);

Answer (score 0):

you can initialze the `snomed_allergies` with an empty ArrayList to avoid null-related issue or there might be issue with this function in conversion `CommonConverter.fromObjectString`, further information is needed.

```
@Entity(tableName = DBConstants.TABLE_USER_PROFILE, indices = {@Index(value = {DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_USERID}, unique = true)})
public class User extends BaseProfileInfo implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_ROWID)
    private int rowId;

    @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_USERID)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_USERID)
    private int id;

    @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_SNOMED_ALERGIES)
    @ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_USER_PROFILE_SNOMED_ALERGIES)
    @Nullable
    public List<SnomedAllergy> snomed_allergies = new ArrayList<>();
}
```